# How to store a list of data in python

Tags: python

```
def pk():
    with open('doc.csv') as csv_file:
        lines = csv_file.readlines()
        for line in lines[1::]:
            array = line.split(',')
            list_pk = array[1].replace('"', '')
            # print(list_pk)
            return list_pk
print(pk())
```

I wonder why when I print `list_pk` just right in front of `return` it prints all extracted data, but when I print `pk()` it prints only the first row. What should I do to get the list of data when I print `pk()`?

Comment: What exactly does `list_pk` contain?

Comment: You really want to avoid re-inventing wheels. The Python standard library has a `csv` module, use that! See [Skip the headers when editing a csv file using Python](//stackoverflow.com/a/14257599) to see how to best skip the first row without reading the whole file into a list first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently returning your list after only a single run through your `for` loop. The `return` statement breaks out of loops. You could accumulate results in your `for` loop and then move the `return` statement to after it:

```
def pk():
    with open('doc.csv') as csv_file:
        lines = csv_file.readlines()
        full_list = []
        for line in lines[1::]:
            array = line.split(',')
            list_pk = array[1].replace('"', '')
            full_list.append(list_pk)  # accumulate results
        return full_list  # return the full result
```